# LazyDataModel called twice

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces

I'm using datatable from primefaces for displaying list of records.
But it call twice the load internal method(overriden) while navigating to pages. This behavior affects the performance.

partial server side code:

```
public void getInternalList() {    
    try {

        dataList = service.getInternalDetails(userId, 0, 5);

        if (null != dataList) {

            // Getting the current page data using lazy loading
            lazyModelEmployees = new LazyDataModel<Employee>() {
                @Override
                public List<Employee> load(int first, int pageSize, String arg2, SortOrder arg3, Map<String, String> arg4) {
                    List<Employee> currentPageEmployeeList = null;

                    try {
                        currentPageEmployeeList = service.getInternalDetails(userId, first, pageSize);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        exceptionHandler(e);
                    }

                    if (arg2 != null) {
                        Collections.sort(currentPageEmployeeList, new LazySorter(arg2, arg3));
                    }
                    int dataSize = currentPageEmployeeList.size();
                    this.setRowCount(dataSize);

                    if (dataSize > pageSize) {
                        try {
                            return currentPageEmployeeList.subList(first, first + pageSize);
                        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException e) {
                            return currentPageEmployeeList.subList(first, first + (dataSize % pageSize));
                        }
                    } else {
                        return currentPageEmployeeList;
                    }

                }
            };
            lazyModelEmployees.setRowCount(dataList.size());
            lazyModelEmployees.setPageSize(5);
        }
    } catch (Exception e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Is your value of the `p:dataTable` is `#{managedBean.internalList}`. Initialize you `internalList` in the `@PostConstruct`. Otherwise the `LazyDataModel` will be called twice or more.

Comment: That's not the correct way to use the `LazyDataModel`. You should have a look at [Primefaces showcase](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/datatableLazy.jsf) in order to understand that you have to override the load method in your custom bean, extending the `LazyDataModel` class.